# Jquery multiple Slidetoggle leads to page shake

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a webpage which has 5 div stacked on top of each other. There are 5 hidden div which i will make visible when a div is clicked. The problem is that when there's overflow a scroll bar appears in the browser window and the entire content flickers and shifts to the left. when the overflow is nullified the content again shifts back to its original position.

Comment: bcoz the vertical scroll bar is showing when the page down...if you dont want the scroll bar give `overflow-y : hidden` to the body tag

Comment: @RHR give him some example...

Comment: `body { overflow-y: hidden; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the overflow of the body tag to scroll, it will show the scrollbar all the time. This way the scroll bar wont appear when you go beyond the fold, it will already be there...

```
body{
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: yes i tried this one. it looks real bad. any other solution will be appreciated.

Comment: The only other solution is to hide the scroll bar all together.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your page height increase and your browser show vertical scrollbar . 
best way to solve this problem is make one of your skill div expand when your page load to make browser scrollbar visible